# Using regexp_replace in update

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a db column report_name which will have values similar to this

```
000007091_PaymentRegisterReport _D x3A 975844_2012-12-26.XLS
```

I need to delete the space before _D in all PaymentRegisterReport with XLS extension.
Could somebody help me with the regex to use inside regexp_replace function in the update statement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you really need a regex to update the data? Please check the query.

```
update TableName
set report_name=REPLACE(report_name, ' _D' , '_D')
WHERE report_name LIKE '%PaymentRegisterReport %' AND 
  report_name LIKE '%.XLS';
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression that you need to use is

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(f1, '(.*)(_PaymentRegisterReport) _D (.*)(\.XLS)$', '\1\2_D\3\4')
```

I am assuming that you can identify the report type by 'PaymentRegisterReport' and the file extensions will be in uppercase

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the " _D" bi "_D" with a select as said techdo.

But I wrote a regex_replace as you was asking :

```
select regexp_replace('000007091_PaymentRegisterReport _D x3A 975844_2012-12-26.XLS','^(.*) _D(.*).XLS$','\1_D\2.XLS') from dual;
```